# how can I merge git commit from one repo to another repo?

Tags: git, merge

Say I have one repo named A, and A has a source file folder A_dir, where I have a <commit_id> on the source files in A_dir
Now I have another different repo named B, B has the same source file folder B_dir, is there any ways I can apply <commit_id> in B_dir?

What I tried is :

1. in A_dir:
   git format-patch <commit_id> -1 # to generate a patch file, say 0001.patch
2. switch to B_dir:

```
    cp A_dir/0001.patch .
    git apply --check 0001.patch
    git apply 0001.patch
```

But the result is the patch seems not applied, When I use "git status" in B, it only reports:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        0001.patch
```

Comment: The procedure you posted is reasonable. The problem is elsewhere, not in the procedure. Most likely, the edit that the patch wants to apply is in conflict with the status quo in the destination directory. You should have posted the output of `git apply --check -v`.

Comment: That said, it is probably easier to just (in B_dir) `git fetch ../A_dir main && git cherry_pick <commit_id>` (this assumes that this commit is reachable from the fetched branch `main`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the result is the patch seems not applied,

Check first if `B_dir` is a a subdirectory of a repository.
From [`git apply` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply):

> When running from a subdirectory in a repository, patched paths outside the directory are ignored

Make sure to apply the patch from the root folder of the target repository, using the [`--directory` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---directoryltrootgt)

> Prepend `<root>` to all filenames.
> If a "`-p`" argument was also passed, it is applied before prepending the new root.
>
> For example, a patch that talks about updating `a/git-gui.sh` to `b/git-gui.sh` can be applied to the file in the working tree `modules/git-gui/git-gui.sh` by running `git apply --directory=modules/git-gui`.